# How can i set my container parameters from consul values through docker?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, consul

I have few simple java applications and i want them to use consul for runtime configuration. I can't understand the approach that should be used at this combo: docker + consul + apps.

I've managed to customize a proper docker-compose.yml file with required containers: consul, jetty1, jetty2, jetty3. Each jetty gets a war application on build. When i docker-compose up my stack i have a proper applications started.
But i can't understand what should i do to make my apps read consul config from the consul service.

I've made such docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '2'

services:
  consuldns:
    build: ./consul
    command: 'agent -server -bootstrap-expect=1 -ui -client=0.0.0.0 -node=consuldns -log-level=debug'
    ports:
      - '8300:8300'
      - '8301:8301'
      - '8302:8302'
      - '8400:8400'
      - '8500:8500'
      - '8600:53/udp'
    container_name: 'consuldns' 
  jettyok1:    
    build: ./jetty
    ports:
      - "8081:8080"     
    container_name: jettyok1  
    depends_on: 
      - consuldns
  jettyok2:    
    build: ./jetty
    ports:
      - "8082:8080"     
    container_name: jettyok2    
    depends_on: 
      - consuldns
  jettyok3:    
    build: ./jetty
    ports:
      - "8083:8080"     
    container_name: jettyok3
    depends_on: 
      - consuldns
```

i have two folders near docker-compose.yml file:
- consul:
 Dockerfile (copied from official repo)

```
FROM consul:latest

ENV CONSUL_TEMPLATE_VERSION 0.18.1

ADD https://releases.hashicorp.com/consul-template/${CONSUL_TEMPLATE_VERSION}/consul-template_${CONSUL_TEMPLATE_VERSION}_linux_amd64.zip /

RUN unzip consul-template_${CONSUL_TEMPLATE_VERSION}_linux_amd64.zip && \
    mv consul-template /usr/local/bin/consul-template &&\
    rm -rf /consul-template_${CONSUL_TEMPLATE_VERSION}_linux_amd64.zip && \
    mkdir -p /etc/consul-template/config.d/templates && \
    apk add --no-cache curl

RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache jq

RUN mkdir /etc/consul.d
RUN echo '{"service": {"name": "my_java_application", "tags": ["java"], "port": 8080}}' > /etc/consul.d/java.json
#RUN consul agent -data-dir /consul/data -config-dir /etc/consul.d

CMD ["agent", "-dev", "-client", "0.0.0.0"]
```

- jetty:
  Dockerfile (handmade)

```
FROM jetty:latest

ENV DEFAULT_SYSTEM_MESSAGE='dockerfile default message'

COPY \always-healthy.war /var/lib/jetty/webapps/
```

always-healthy.war is a simple spring-boot web app with a single GET method support:

```
package org.bajiepka.demo.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;

@RestController
public class MessageController {

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @GetMapping("/message")
    public String getDefaultMessage(){
        return String.format("Current value: %s", environment.getProperty("DEFAULT_SYSTEM_MESSAGE"));
    }
}
```

Point me please, what should i do, to make my always-healthy apps read a value from consul service so i could manage an env parameter DEFAULT_SYSTEM_MESSAGE of any jetty instance or always-healthy application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Spring cloud you could use Spring cloud consul config to enable the app to load the configuration from consul at the startup.

See samples and example [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-consul) and [here](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-consul/2.0.x/multi/multi_spring-cloud-consul-config.html)

If you are not using spring cloud then it is a bit more work where you have to fetch the configuration using a rest client from consul.

Comment: is there any solution or a tool, to do this without rest template?